# R dplyr replace value based on match with another table

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I'am having a hard time to solve something simple.

I am trying to replace a value in a specific column based in a match with a second table.

I can use the replace to create condition in the same table, such as:

```
data <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = replace(mpg, cyl == 4, NA))
```

But I need to mutate and replace based on a second table, considering they have a matching table.
Consider I have a second table named color.
I would like to replace the mtcars$color to true or false based in the condition of mtcars$cyl exists in color$cyl.

```
cyl color
4   blue
6   green
8   yellow
1   red
2   black
3   purple

data <- mtcars %>% mutate(color = replace(color, cyl == color$cyl, TRUE))
```

Would be possible to use mutate and replace or I would need to use a match
or other functions?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use replace because the column `color` does not yet exist in `mtcars`. (This is different to your first example, where you worked with `mpg`, which is an existing column.)

Also, `cyl == color$cly` is not the correct test, because it is for element-wise comparison. If I understand you correctly, you want to check for each value of `mtcars$cyl`, wheter that value appears *anywhere* in `color$cyl`. You can use `%in%` for this purpose.

The following two lines add a column `color` to mtcars that contains `TRUE` for each row that has a value in `cyl` that can also be found in `color$cyl`. As it so happens, this is true for all rows.

```
data <- mtcars %>%
        mutate(color = cyl %in% color$cyl)
head(data)
##    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb color
## 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  TRUE
## 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  TRUE
## 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  TRUE
## 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  TRUE
## 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  TRUE
## 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I wasn't aware of the `%in%` use for this situation. Actually, I don't recall ever seen that operator rsrsrs. That is exactly what I was looking for. I was looking in the wrong place the whole time. Thanks again.